# Simple coalgebra under base change

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Let $C$ be a simple coalgebra over a field of characteristic $0$. Let $K$ be a field extension of $k$. Is the coalgebra  $C\otimes_k K$ over $K$ simple?

Comment: No. Simple coalgebras are dual to simple algebras, but the simplicity of an algebra is not invariant under base change (for example, $\mathbb{C}$ is a simple $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, but does not stay simple if you base-change to $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: @grinberg Thanks!